# how to display circular progress IUP_CircleProgressAnimation in IupAnimatedLabel

Tags: lua, iup

Here is minimal working code:

```
require("iuplua")
require( "iupluacontrols" )
require("iupluaimglib")

label_1 = iup.label {title = "The label                "}
label_2 = iup.label {image = "IUP_ActionOk"}

-- NOT WORK 
--label_3 = iup.AnimatedLabel(NULL);
--iup.SetAttribute(label, "ANIMATION", "IUP_CircleProgressAnimation");
--iup.SetAttribute(label, "START", "Yes");

vbox = iup.vbox{
                 label_1
                ,label_2
                --, label_3
}


dlg = iup.dialog{
  vbox
}


dlg:showxy(iup.CENTER,iup.CENTER)
dlg.usersize = nil

-- to be able to run this script inside another context
if (iup.MainLoopLevel()==0) then
  iup.MainLoop()
  iup.Close()
end
```

The example is taken from the help, but unfortunately, what is commented on-does not work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
label_3 = iup.animatedlabel{}
label_3.animation = "IUP_CircleProgressAnimation"
label_3.start = "Yes"
```

Just tested and your sample worked.